# Make discord bot join a vc using an id from json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

So I want my bot for everytime it boots up I want it to join a specific vc and to play some music! Although, I have come accross a problem. I tried doing this with an id and it worked fine but doing it with json causes some errors and keeps saying that it can't join of undefined. Here is my code:

Processor:

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core-discord');
const editJsonFile = require("edit-json-file");
var fs = require('file-system');
var path = require('path');
const ytfps = require('ytfps');

const prefix = "v_";

let value = true;
let temp;



exports.run = async (client, message, args, ops) => {
  const idchannel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === "815183065843499008");
  const ytchannel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === "815183091244597248");

  let song = editJsonFile(`live/song.json`);
  song.save();
  let channelid = editJsonFile(`live/channelid.json`);
  song.save();
  let count = editJsonFile(`live/count.json`);
  count.save();
  let cloud = editJsonFile(`live/could.json`);
  cloud.save();

  let v = count.get(`v`);
  let check = cloud.get(`${v}`);
  let ope = channelid.get(`${v}`);
  if (ope == undefined){
    setTimeout(function() {
      delete require.cache[require.resolve(`./liveplay.js`)];

      let commandFile = require(`./liveplay.js`);
      commandFile.run(client, message);
    }, 1000);
  }
  const voiceChannel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === `${ope}`);
  if (voiceChannel == undefined){
    setTimeout(function() {
      delete require.cache[require.resolve(`./liveplay.js`)];

      let commandFile = require(`./liveplay.js`);
      commandFile.run(client, message);
    }, 1000);
  }
  console.log(`${ope}`);

setTimeout(async function() {
  try {
    console.log("BIP");
      setTimeout(async function() {
        connection = await voiceChannel.join();
      }, 100);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
      const embed = {
          "url": "https://discordapp.com",
          "color": 16747962,
          "fields": [
              {
                  "name": " Error ",
                  "value": "There was an error connecting to the voice channel!"
              }
          ]
      };
    return message.channel.send({ embed });
  }
}, 5000);
setTimeout(async function() {
    let ope2 = song.get(`${v}`);
     dispatcher = connection.play(await ytdl(ope2), { type: 'opus' })
    .on('finish', () => {
      voiceChannel.leave();

    })
    .on('error', error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
    dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(5 / 5);
  }, 7000);
  count.set(`v`, v-1);
  count.save();
  v = count.get(`v`);
  if (v < 0){
    count.set(`v`, v+1);
    count.save();
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      delete require.cache[require.resolve(`./liveplay.js`)];

      let commandFile = require(`./liveplay.js`);
      commandFile.run(client, message);
    }, 8000);
  }
}
```

Here is the join command where it actually works:

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core-discord');
const editJsonFile = require("edit-json-file");
var fs = require('file-system');
var path = require('path');
const ytfps = require('ytfps');

const prefix = "v_";



exports.run = async (client, message, args, ops) => {
        var value = false;

        let number = editJsonFile(`premium/premium.json`);
        number.save();
        let count = editJsonFile(`premium/count.json`);
        count.save();

        let v = count.get(`v`)
        for(var i = 0; i <= v; i++){
          let check = number.get(`${i}`)
          if (check == message.author.id){
            value = true;
          }
        }
        if(value == false){
          return message.channel.send("You do not have premium so you cant run this command");
        } else {
              args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");
              const voiceChannel =  client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === "809466736491233294");
                  try {
                    setTimeout(async function() {
                      connection = await voiceChannel.join();
                    }, 500);

                  } catch(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                  }
        }

}
```

EDIT: ope is suppose to equal to the channel id!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i might not be right on this but it seems like your not properly catching the error!

it says that the channel is undefined, that can mean a lot of things. maybe you gave a wrong channel id, maybe a wrong guild id, only way to know for sure is to closely check your code for typos.

as for the error catching, try this:

```
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get("ChannelIDhere");
if (!channel) return console.error("The channel does not exist!");
channel.join().then(connection => {
    // Yay, it worked!
    console.log("Successfully connected.");
}).catch(e => {
    // Oh no, it errored! Let's log it to console :)
    console.error(`Failed to connect to the channel! Error:\n${e}`
```

oh and you forgot to put `var` before you defined connection

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna export the data from a json file you need to do `editJsonFile = require('edit-json-file')` then `channel.id === ${editJsonFilewhat.channelid}` or what ever u define the vc as in json file
in this example in the json file is

```json
{
    "channelid":"815183065843499008"
}
```